# Is It possible to find necessary parameters 4 GET/POST requests in jQuery.ajaxSettings?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, reverse-engineering

Let me begin by saying that everything I do is for educational purposes only. It's really interesting and important to understand *"how it works"*. That's all. Nobody, nobody is hurt. So, right know I am learning reverse engineering and I was stooped with understanding of Jquery.ajaxs, 4 example I have a [source](https://www.globus.ru/catalog/myaso-ptitsa-kolbasy/?count=36) and I know how to get many Interesting things(**go to source and in browser, console puts** *'> ECProductImpressionTrackingArray'*):
[image]

Also you can get some Info if u will puts *'jQuery.ajaxSettings'*.

Among other things, I found [link](https://www.globus.ru/bitrix/services/main/ajax.php?), Its serves to get product data and now I am interesting, If it possible to find "*the right query params*" to get data. Maybe I can do it with *'jQuery.ajaxSettings'* or should I find it in another place. By the way, why people still use jQuery, is its safety?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S. Found smth interesting:**

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} action
 * @param {Object} config
 * @param {?string|?Object} [config.analyticsLabel]
 * @param {string} [config.method='POST']
 * @param {Object} [config.data]
 * @param {?Object} [config.getParameters]
 * @param {?Object} [config.headers]
 * @param {?Object} [config.timeout]
 * @param {Object} [config.navigation]
 * @param {number} [config.navigation.page]
 */
BX.ajax.runAction = function(action, config)
{
    config = prepareAjaxConfig(config);
    var getParameters = prepareAjaxGetParameters(config);
    getParameters.action = action;

    var url = '/bitrix/services/main/ajax.php?' + BX.ajax.prepareData(getParameters);

    return buildAjaxPromiseToRestoreCsrf({
        method: config.method,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: config.data,
        timeout: config.timeout,
        preparePost: config.preparePost,
        headers: config.headers,
        onrequeststart: config.onrequeststart
    });
};

/**
 *
 * @param {string} component
 * @param {string} action
 * @param {Object} config
 * @param {?string|?Object} [config.analyticsLabel]
 * @param {?string} [config.signedParameters]
 * @param {string} [config.method='POST']
 * @param {string} [config.mode='ajax'] Ajax or class.
 * @param {Object} [config.data]
 * @param {?Object} [config.getParameters]
 * @param {?array} [config.headers]
 * @param {?number} [config.timeout]
 * @param {Object} [config.navigation]
 */
BX.ajax.runComponentAction = function (component, action, config)
{
    config = prepareAjaxConfig(config);
    config.mode = config.mode || 'ajax';

    var getParameters = prepareAjaxGetParameters(config);
    getParameters.c = component;
    getParameters.action = action;

    var url = '/bitrix/services/main/ajax.php?' + BX.ajax.prepareData(getParameters);

    return buildAjaxPromiseToRestoreCsrf({
        method: config.method,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: config.data,
        timeout: config.timeout,
        preparePost: config.preparePost,
        headers: config.headers,
        onrequeststart: (config.onrequeststart ? config.onrequeststart : null)
    });
};
```

Comment: As to “why people still use jQuery”, that is a subjective question (which is not a good fit on this site) which has tons of answers, but as it relates specifically to “still” I think they can mostly be summarized by “momentum”.

Comment: If you really want to know what is going on with a site, look at the HTTP requests. Some will be AJAX/fetch and some will “standard”. Look at the query string, POST body and cookies. That’s where most interesting things ultimately end up happening.

Comment: @ChrisHaas hmm, ok, thank you Chris, let me try and think about what you're saying.